# Defining lines from a heightmap

Tags: xna, hlsl, fragment-shader, heightmap

To a pixel shader of a 2D game, I'm passing a 1-row heightmap that holds the height in UV coordinates of evenly distributed points throughout the texture I'm drawing, but as for *n points* there will obviously be *n-1 lines* connecting consecutive ones, I can't make these lines as wide as they should be. 
For example, filling the pixels below the lines of a heightmap that holds 3 values (`{0f, 1f, .5f}`) should result in something like:
[image]

but instead, it looks like this:
[image]

It is visible that the correct result lies on the first 2/3 of the second one, and the last 1/3 comes from clamping the heightmap.

Here is a simpler version of the pixel shader code.

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float4 texCoords:TEXCOORD0):COLOR0
{
    float verticesCount = 3;
    float verticesFrequency = 1/verticesCount;

    float lastHeight = tex2D(heightMapSampler, float2(texCoords.x, 0));
    float nextHeight = tex2D(heightMapSampler, float2(texCoords.x + verticesFrequency, 0));

    float delta = (texCoords.x % verticesFrequency)/verticesFrequency;
    float height = lerp(lastHeight, nextHeight, delta);
    if(texCoords.y > height)
        return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    return float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

I tried multiplying the texture coordinates by `(verticesCount-1)/verticesCount` but that didn't seem to do the job. Thank you!

Comment: Multiplying `texCoords.x` by `(verticesCount-1)/verticesCount` at the top should really do the trick, I'd think.  What goes wrong for you in that case?  Can you post a screenshot of the result?

Comment: I tried multiplying the texture coordinates when sampling of lastHeight and nextHeight, only after reading your comment I noticed I could change the texCoords values, and that did work! You should post it as an answer, because it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying `texCoords.x` by `(verticesCount-1)/verticesCount` at the top should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In this line verticesFrequency becomes equal to one third

```
float verticesFrequency = 1/verticesCount;
```

On this line you are adding one third to the texture coordinate

```
float nextHeight = tex2D(heightMapSampler, float2(texCoords.x + verticesFrequency, 0));
```

So for the first pixel you are sampling texture coordinate [0.333, 0] but you want to be sampling [0.5, 0] i.e. the middle of the three coordinates.

Perhaps you should use verticesCount - 1